# Python create sublists based on condition

Tags: python, list

I have a list that I want to make sublists from it based on the percentage change of the elements inside the list. For example:

```
list=[11.7, 8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8, 1.05]
plist = [100.0 * e1 / e2 - 100 for e1, e2 in zip(list[1:], list)]
```

plist is:

```
[-27.350427350427353, 32.94117647058823, -0.8849557522123916, 
 -3.5714285714285694, -90.27777777777777]
```

Any consecutive element's percentage change > -5 will get grouped into a sublist like,

```
[11.7, [8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8], 1.05]
```

Are there any other ways to get the desired output without using the long list comprehension method?

Comment: don't use `list` as variable name!

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that.

Comment: This is unclear: `"Any consecutive element's percentage change > -5 will get grouped into a sublist like, "`

Answer (score 1):

```
l=[11.7, 8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8, 1.05, 11.7, 8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8, 1.05]
print(l)

ul=[l[0]]
l2=[]
i=0
flag = True
while i < len(l)-1:
    x = 100.0 * l[i+1] / l[i] - 100
    if x > (-5):
        if l[i] not in l2:
            l2.append(l[i])
        if l[i+1] not in l2:
            l2.append(l[i+1])
    else:
        l2=[]
        if i !=0: 
            ul.append(l[i+1])
    if l2:
        if l2 not in ul:
            ul.append(l2)
    i+=1
print(ul)
```

Output 1

```
[11.7, 8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8, 1.05]
[11.7, [8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8], 1.05]
```

Output 2

```
[11.7, 8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8, 1.05, 11.7, 8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8, 1.05]
[11.7, [8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8], 1.05, [1.05, 11.7], 8.5, [8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8], 1.05]
```

The items `8.5` and `1.05` are present in both lists; I think that's expected.

Additional details

```
0 11.7 -27.350427350427353
1 8.5 32.94117647058823
2 11.3 -0.8849557522123916
3 11.2 -3.5714285714285694
4 10.8 -90.27777777777777
5 1.05 1014.2857142857142
6 11.7 -27.350427350427353
7 8.5 32.94117647058823
8 11.3 -0.8849557522123916
9 11.2 -3.5714285714285694
10 10.8 -90.27777777777777
```

Comment: This will not work if multiple sublists are required

Answer (score 1):

You will need to track whether or not a sublist is underway. Something like this will work:

```
values = [11.7, 8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8, 1.05]  # 'list' is a bad name
grouped_values = [values[0]]
sublist = None
for x, y in zip(values[:-1], values[1:]):
    change = 100.0 * y / x - 100.0
    if change > -5:
        if sublist is None:
            sublist = []
        sublist.append(y)
    else:
        if sublist is not None:
            grouped_values.append(sublist)
            sublist = None
        grouped_values.append(y)
if sublist is not None:
    grouped_values.append(sublist)
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't clearly get your criteria with the example of the expected output however. You may apply the following:

```
Values = [11.7, 8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8, 1.05]
```

First you determine the positions of change in the list (The if condition here is my understanding of 5% change you might want to change this according to your needs)

```
ChangePosition = [ Ind+1 for Ind,Pair in enumerate(zip(Values,Values[1:]))
                    if ((Pair [0] - Pair [1]) / Pair [0] > -0.05) ]
```

Then you add the beginning and the end of the possible positions.

```
ChangePosition = [0] + ChangePosition + [len(Values)]
```

Finally you slice the Values according to these positions:

```
GroupedValues = [ Values[Start:Finish] if (Finish-Start)> 1 else Values[Start]
for Start,Finish in zip(ChangePosition ,ChangePosition [1:])]
```

Answer (score 0):

starting from lxop 'answer' I made this, I believe, working code

the hint is fine but the only flag you need is whether `sublist` is empty or not `if sublist != []`

I did add `[values[-1]/2]` to `values[1:]` so the `zip` doesn't cut off the last element of `values`

Then the calculation with `x` = `values[-1]/2` forces the last element of `values` (= `y`) into the `else` clause which does the right thing re the last element being in the last sublist or not

```
values = [11.7, 8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8, 5, 1.05, 1.9, 1]

grouped_values, sublist = [], []

for x, y in zip(values[1:] + [values[-1]/2], values):

    if 100.0 * (x / y - 1) > -5:
        sublist.append(y)
    else:
        if sublist != []:
            sublist.append(y)
            grouped_values.append(sublist)
            sublist = []
        else:
            grouped_values.append(y)


grouped_values
Out[181]: [11.7, [8.5, 11.3, 11.2, 10.8], 5, [1.05, 1.9], 1]
```